# Shimano XT-Alivio compatibility

Tags: derailleur, shimano, shifter

I am going to buy a Shimano XT rear derailleur, but currently I am using Shimano Alivio M4000 shifter. I would like to know if these two components are compatible?

Answer (score 2):

The Alvio M4000 is a 9 speed shifter,
as long as your XT derailleur is a 9 speed version it will be fine

Comment: It doesn't have to be a 9 speed version, but it has to be a <10 speed version due to a change in cable pull.